# Change IP address of the network card?

Tags: windows-7, windows, networking, router, ip-address

How can I change IP address of my network card which have an odd IP address `169.254.57.200` which is not known by my router?

My router has IP addresses `192.168.0.2` - `168.168.0.254` I have problems with this computer contacting the network or Internet, I have tried to change with cmd  `ipconfig /release` and `/renew`, but it did not work.  Network card still has the same IP address...

Ideas or suggestions?

Comment: What’s the `168.168.0.254`? The subnet mask? If so, did you set that?

Comment: @Synetech `192.168.0.2 - 254` is the DCHP scope.

Comment: @iglvzx, and the `168.168.0`?

Comment: @Synetech Oh, wow. I did not notice the extra `168`. A typo most likely, but we do need some clarification.

Comment: @iglvzx, um, look at it again: `192.168.0.2 - 168.168.0.254` *> I did not notice the extra `168`* There are **two** extra `168`’s and an extra `0`. *> A typo most likely* Actually, it’s **not** likely a typo; there are clearly two addresses, including a dash with spaces on either side. That would be the strangest typo ever. Also, check the [original version of the question](http://superuser.com/posts/235263/revisions); that part is the same.

Comment: @Synetech Let me rephrase. It looks like they meant to say "My router has an IP address range of `192.168.0.2 - 192.168.0.254`". The hyphen signifying 'to'. I condensed it to `192.168.0.2 - 254` when I first replied to you here. That's why I think it's a typo.

Comment: Oh, so you think the first `168` was supposed to be a `192`? **That** *would* be a typo then. (Too bad they have not returned to explain or pick up proposed answers.)

Answer (score 4):

That IP looks like a random one as assigned by windows if you are unable to get a DHCP address. First make sure your router is functioning as a DHCP server and that your DHCP pool isn't full. If want to set an IP manually: go to the network and sharing center and on the left pane click on "change adapter settings". Right click the device that is connected and click properties, after selecting ipv4 settings click properties again. From here you can manually enter the IP address, make sure to set your gateway as your routers IP and DNS to either the router, local DNS server, or your preferred  DNS provider like Google. You should be okay after doing this and have internet access assuming you didn't give your device an IP that is already in use.

Comment: More precisely, a [link-local address](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/APIPA).

Answer (score 0):

To add to Kyle's point, the address 8.8.8.8 is a Google DNS server I use when I need to. It sounds like your router isn't functioning properly as a DHCP server.. you could login to your router's IP address (address is cmd > ipconfig > default gateway ip). Google the router's default username/password if you don't have it on hand. You can then reconfigure as necessary or see if it's assigning the same IP to multiple systems.

Other idea: statically set your IP to something in the range and see if you can get connectivity.

If you mention your OS I can be more specific on how to do these things (XP / Vista / 7).

Answer (score 0):

The address you have is a zero-config address.  This is usable only for the local network.  You end up with this because you are not getting a DHCP address from your router.  Possible solutions.

1. Check that you have DHCP enabled on your router.  If you have multiple computers connected to the router make sure your range is larger than the number of computers connecting.
2. Your network cable may not be working well.  Disconnect and reconnect it. Try replacing it if you have a spare.  For wireless, you may not have the right security key.
3. You can manually add an address by opening the configuration for the card from the Network setting menu.  Use and address like 192.168.0.9.
4. In the routers menu you may be able to manually add routing entries.  If so, try adding 169.245.0.0/16.  If it uses  a netmask, the mask is 255.255.0.0.  Set the router address to something like 169.254.0.1 if you need an address.

Answer (score 0):

You likely need to configure your router. There are a few options/steps, in order of severity (more detailed information can be specified if you provide the model of your router):

1. Try opening the TCP/IP Properties dialog and setting the IP manually to 192.168.0.3 to see if you can get network access at all
2. Open a browser and navigate to your router’s address (normally `http://192.168.0.1`) and find the DHCP section of the configuration panel. You can probably configure it to be a dynamic or static server with several more options (check the MAC address and copy/clone it from your system if your NIC has changed)
3. If you do not have specific, custom settings for your router, try pressing the Reset button briefly to do a simple reset, but if it still doesn’t work, try holding the Reset button for 10-20 seconds to do a full reset-to-default

Comment: I think `192.168.0.1` would be the router/gateway in this case.

Comment: @iglvzx, normally yes, but they said `192.168.0.2` We’ll have to wait for a clarification.